# A curious case of closure. Can anyone explain how this works?

Tags: javascript

I stumbled upon this solution to a problem I had by using a closure, but I have no idea why it actually works, and why my original code did not.

I have a helper function that takes a default_object. It returns another function that takes some object and uses it to fill in values for the default object:

```
function DTO(default_object){
    return function (object) {

        var dto = default_object;

        for (key in default_object) {
            if (key in object) {
                dto[key] = object[key];
            }
        }
        return dto;
    }
}
```

I then use this function like so:

```
var user = function(object) {
        return DTO({
            name: null,
            color: "#ffffff",
            public_id: null,
        })(object);
    }

var clean_users = []
unclean_users.forEach(function(unclean_user){
    clean_users.push(user(unclean_user));
});
```

Which returns an array of safe user objects.
Originally I had:

```
var user = DTO({
            name: null,
            color: "#ffffff",
            public_id: null,
        });
    }
```

Which I assumed would perform the same way because DTO returns a function, but this makes clean_users filled with the same user (the first one) over and over again.

I was under the impression that executing user in the loop would create a new function taking a new unclean_user as an argument each time and returning a new clean_user, but for some reason it only happens once.
Can anyone explain why?

Comment: That's what the closure does, it keeps your object in memory, the same one. What you are doing is basically partially applying a function vs creating a function that creates a new object that then partially applies the function and finally calls it with the new object. See the difference?

Comment: points for the doyle-esqe phrasing of the question title

Comment: `clean_users filled with the same user (the first one) over and over again.` was it the first or the *last*?

Comment: @manojlds definitely the first. You can try it out yourself right now if you like... `var unclean_users = [{ name: "bob" }, {}, {}]`

Comment: @elclanrs Haha, not quite yet. In the `forEach` loop, a different `unclean_user` is being passed to `user()` at each iteration. I don't really understand why those are completely unaccounted for and the first one is just copied over and over. Doesn't each execution of `user(unclean_user)` equal `DTO({...})(unclean_user)` which should return a new user each time?

Comment: You can just change `var dto = default_object;` to `var dto = Object.create(default_object);` and keep your first version.

Comment: in your original solution you are using the same object literal all over again. on your working solution you create new one whenever you call user()

Comment: I tried to explain what I meant in my solution, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 3):

> DTO returns a function

Yes, it does.

> but this makes clean_users filled with the same user (the first one) over and over again.

Yes, because the function returned by `DTO(o)` returns the same object `o` every time. Your problem is the line

> ```
>  var dto = default_object;
> ```

which **does not create a copy**, but assigns a reference to the very same object to a different variable. Your original code works because it does create new objects via the literal every time `user` is called, but your new function just returns the very same object on each `user` call.

You will have to change your code so that the returned function creates a new object every time and copies the properties from `default_object`:

```
function DTO(default_object){
    return function (object) {
        var dto = {};
        for (key in default_object) {
            if (key in object) {
                dto[key] = object[key];
            } else {
                dto[key] = default_object[key];
            }
        }
        return dto;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without the second closure, you only call `DTO()` once. `DTO()` is written in such a way that it takes in an object, and returns a function that would only work on the object that was passed to `DTO`. So, when you call `user()`, you modify the same object that was originally passed to `DTO()` when you called it.

As you `push` the results of `user()`, you store references of the same object, as that object gets modified throughout your last loop, at the end, your `clean_users` will contain references to that same object. Those aren't different objects that look the same, if you looked inside the array before you went through all `unclean_users`, you would see that.

Adding that second closure makes `user()` function return a function that would call `DTO()` with the object that it (`user()`) was called with. Which is what you want in this case. Then `DTO()` will work on a new object every time `user()` is called.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `DTO` function. This line: `var dto = default_object;` creates a reference to an object saved in the closure which is then is modified every time the function DTO is called. In addition, the function DTO returns always a reference to the same object `dto`, that's why the array is filled with the same values.

This fixes the issue:

```
  function clone(ob) {
   return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ob));                                                      
  }

  function DTO(default_object){
    return function (object) {

        var dto = clone(default_object);

       for (key in default_object) {
           if (key in object) {
               dto[key] = object[key];
          }
       }
       return dto; 
   }         
 }
```

This fixes the issue because it creates a new object every time the function is called.

**Why does it work when the function`DTO` is called within a closure?**

```
var user = function(object) {
        return DTO({
            name: null,
            color: "#ffffff",
            public_id: null,
        })(object);
    }
```

In the above code snippet, the function `DTO` is called for **each** object in the array, whereas in the second case is called just once. Therefore, a `default_object` is created each time the function is called.

**JSFIDDLE** 
https://jsfiddle.net/y2enopok/
Open the console to see the result.

**Note**
I suggest to use a better clone function. For example [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) from lodash.

Comment: I wouldn't use that clone function. `var dto = default_object.slice()` works just fine to make a copy and is a lot cleaner and better performing.

Comment: Yeah, that's the first thing pop up in my mind. Thanks I update my answer

Comment: @AllTheTime, `slice` is an Array method, calling it on an object will throw an error.

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett it must be getting late... thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @AllTheTime I think the best thing to do here is to use `clone`.  The first code is buggy as it doesn't copy over all the fields from the default object unless they are in the `object`.

Answer (score 1):

> **JavaScript Closure**

A closure is an inner function that has access to the outer (enclosing) function's variables—scope chain. The closure has three scope chains:

- It has access to its own scope (variables defined between its curly brackets),
- It has access to the outer function's variables,
- It has access to the global variables

When you write a function in this way means,

```
(function(){

})();
```

simply writing your code directly without any function but, the variables has scope to that closure function only.

In your case, you are passing an object to closure function, which is hold by `default_object`, and then you are passing this object's pointer to another variable `dto`. And because of this, its using same memory location every time.

> **Solution:**

```
function DTO(default_object) {
  return function(object) {

    var dto = {};

    for (key in default_object) {
      if (key in object) {
        dto[key] = object[key];
      } else {
        dto[key] = default_object[key]
      }
    }
    return dto;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple example may bring some clarity. Think that any function of more than one argument is equivalent in theory to a function of a single argument, that keeps returning functions of one argument, until all arguments have been passed. That is to say:

```
add(1, 2) == add(1)(2) == 3
```

This is what is understood as currying. Notice in `add(1, 2)` all arguments have to be passed when you call the function, while in the other case you could do it in two steps:

```
var add1 = add(1)
add1(2)
```

The `1` is captured in a closure; this `1` will be the same every time you call `add1`, so you got a reusable **partially applied** function.

There is a difference between a function that is naturally curried, like you got, and one that you have to partially apply manually. To illustrate the case, imagine that you are working with the non-curried version `add(1, 2)`, and you want to partially apply `1`:

```
var add1 = function(b) {
  return add(1, b) // equivalent to add(1)(b)
}
```

Now the `1` is re-created every time you call `add1`. This is not equivalent to the partially applied curried function. So, with a number this does not matter, but objects are passed around as value references, which means they are the same object, and are mutable.

In conclusion, the difference is in creating a new object every time vs using the same object captured in a closure.